# How to reduce padding from BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The default comes with the following padding:

```
EdgeInsets(0.0,14.0,0.0,0.0)
```

How can I reduce the padding?

Edit: I can't change the default padding by accessing it directly as suggested in one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it easily like this:

```
    EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have access to the default padding. I only know because I used the "Select Widget Mode". Within the Details Tree I could see the set padding as shown before.

Answer (score 0):

The padding inside BottomNavigationBar is calculated by `selectedFontSize` if the selected icon is as big as unselected icon (by default).

Have you try to set this value to 0?

This is the source inside _BottomNavigationTile

```
// Defines the padding for the animating icons + labels.
//
// The animations go from "Unselected":
// =======
// |      <-- Padding equal to the text height + 1/2 selectedIconDiff.
// |  ☆
// | text <-- Invisible text + padding equal to 1/2 selectedIconDiff.
// =======
//
// To "Selected":
//
// =======
// |      <-- Padding equal to 1/2 text height + 1/2 unselectedIconDiff.
// |  ☆
// | text
// |      <-- Padding equal to 1/2 text height + 1/2 unselectedIconDiff.
// =======
```